How to debug an exception in a multithread server class
I have a socket class that has a separate thread for recv/send data, and it is able to send/receive data correctly.
The part of the logic that is not working and giving me an exception is the part when there is a disconnect from the client and the server has to cleanup everything related to the socket and start listening again.
Please note that the cleanup works the first time, but it is only the second time when a disconnect occurs that I see the exception:

libc++abi: terminating

I cannot debug the application, but I was able to attach a debugger and get the callstack from the  recv thread as below:
raise 0x00007f3873ebeca0
abort 0x00007f3873ec0148
abort_message 0x0000558c4d7dd9b4
demangling_terminate_handler() 0x0000558c4d7dd00d
std::__terminate(void (*)()) 0x0000558c4d7dcf52
std::terminate() 0x0000558c4d7dcea9
std::__1::thread::operator=[abi:v15006](std::__1::thread&&) 0x0000558c4d889eaa
Server::recvThread() 0x0000558c4d8855ec
decltype (((*((std::declval<Server*>)())).*((std::declval<void (Server::*)()>)()))()) std::__1::__invoke[abi:v15006]<void (Server::*)(), Server*, , void>(void (Server::*&&)(), Server*&&) 0x0000558c4d8924f9
void std::__1::__thread_execute[abi:v15006]<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (Server::*)(), Server*, 2ul>(std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (Server::*)(), Server*>&, std::__1::__tuple_indices<2ul>) 0x0000558c4d89247e
void* std::__1::__thread_proxy[abi:v15006]<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (Server::*)(), Server*> >(void*) 0x0000558c4d892252
start_thread 0x00007f3873c7444b
clone 0x00007f3873f7a52f

My Server class looks like below:
class Server{
public:

    ~Server();

    bool listen();
    void setPort(unsigned short port);
    void shutdown();

protected:

    void sendThread();

    void recvThread();

    void acceptThread();

    void resetThread();
 
    void joinThreads(); 

    void cleanUp();
   
    void queueMessage(Message responseMessage);
  
    Message createMessageFromBuffer(std::vector<unsigned char>& byteBuffer);


    std::thread m_sendThread;

    std::thread m_recvThread;
    std::thread m_acceptThread;
    std::thread m_resetThread;

    bool m_isShutdown;

    bool m_needsReset;

    std::mutex m_mutex;

    std::condition_variable m_sendThreadWait;

    int m_listenSocket;


    unsigned short m_port;

    unsigned int m_socketId;

    std::deque<Message> m_messageQueue;
};

My Server.cpp class looks like:
Server::~Server() {
    shutdown();
}

bool Server::listen() {
    std::cout<<"Server::listen\n";
    m_listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (m_listenSocket < 0) {
        std::cout<<"Failed to open listen socket.\n";
        return false;
    }

    int optval = 0;
    if (setsockopt(m_listenSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval)) < 0) {
        std::cout<<"Failed to set SO_REUSEADDR option.\n";
        close(m_listenSocket);
        return false;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(m_port);

    if (bind(m_listenSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        std::cout<<" Failed to bind to port."<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
        close(m_listenSocket);
        return false;
    }

    int backlog = 1;  // We are only interested to pool one client.
    if (::listen(m_listenSocket, backlog) < 0) {
        std::cout<<" Failed to listen on the listen socket."<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
        close(m_listenSocket);
        return false;
    }

    std::cout<<"Server is listening."<<"port"<<m_port<<"\n";

    m_acceptThread = std::thread(&Server::acceptThread, this);

    return true;
}

void Server::setPort(unsigned short port) {
    std::cout<<"port"<<port<<"\n";
    m_port = port;
}

void Server::joinThreads() {
    std::cout<<"Server::joinThreads\n";
    if (m_acceptThread.joinable()) {
        m_acceptThread.join();
    }

    if (m_recvThread.joinable()) {
        m_recvThread.join();
    }

    if (m_sendThread.joinable()) {
        m_sendThread.join();
    }
}

void Server::shutdown() {
    std::cout<<"Server::shutdown\n";
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        if (m_isShutdown) {
            // shutdown already invoked
            return;
        }
        m_isShutdown = true;
    }

    if (m_resetThread.joinable()) {
        m_resetThread.join();
    }

    cleanUp();
}

void Server::cleanUp(){
    std::cout<<"Server::cleanUp\n";
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_messageQueue.clear();
        m_sendThreadWait.notify_one();
    }

    ::shutdown(m_listenSocket, SHUT_RD);
    ::shutdown(m_socketId, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(m_listenSocket);
    close(m_socketId);

    joinThreads();
}

void Server::resetThread() {
    std::cout<<"Server::resetThread::started.\n";
    cleanUp();
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_needsReset = false;
    }
    listen();
    std::cout<<"Server::resetThread::completed.\n";
}

void Server::queuemessage(message message) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_messageQueue.emplace_back(message);
    m_sendThreadWait.notify_one();
}

void Server::sendThread() {
    std::cout<<"Server::sendThread::started.\n";
    try {
        do {
            message message = messageBuilder{}.build();
            {
                std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                m_sendThreadWait.wait(lock, [this] { return m_messageQueue.size() || m_isShutdown || m_needsReset; });
                if (m_isShutdown || m_needsReset) {
                    break;
                }
                message = m_messageQueue.front();
                m_messageQueue.pop_front();
            }

            /// create send payload from message 

            std::string responsePayload = message.toString();

            std::cout<<"Sending Payload"<<responsePayload<<"\n";

            std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(responsePayload.begin(), responsePayload.end());
            int responseLength = responsePayload.size();
            int responseLengthInNetworkByte = htonl(responseLength);
            ssize_t bytesRemaining = responseLength;
            ssize_t bytesAlreadySent = 0;
            send(m_socketId, &responseLengthInNetworkByte, sizeof(int), 0);

            do {
                ssize_t bytes = send(m_socketId, &buffer[0] + bytesAlreadySent, bytesRemaining, 0);
                {
                    std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                    if (m_isShutdown || m_needsReset) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                bytesAlreadySent += bytes;
                bytesRemaining -= bytes;
            } while (bytesRemaining > 0);
        } while (true);
        {
            std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            if (!m_isShutdown && !m_needsReset) {
                std::cout << "SendThread1\n";
                m_needsReset = true;
                m_resetThread = std::thread(&Server::resetThread, this);
                std::cout << "SendThread2\n";
            }
        }
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout<<"send outside exception"<<e.what()<<"\n";
    }
    std::cout<<"Server::sendThread::completed.\n";
}

void Server::acceptThread() {
    try {
        std::cout<<"Server::acceptThread::started.\n";
        socklen_t sockaddrLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        int incomingSocketId = accept(m_listenSocket, NULL, &sockaddrLength);
        if (incomingSocketId < 0) {
            std::cout<<.m("Failed to accept the client connection").d("reason", strerror(errno)));
            return;
        }

        m_socketId = incomingSocketId;

        // Start send and recv thread
        m_sendThread = std::thread(&Server::sendThread, this);
        m_recvThread = std::thread(&Server::recvThread, this);

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout<<"socket closed."<<e.what()<<"\n";
        return;
    }
    std::cout<<"Server::acceptThread::completed.\n";
}

void Server::recvThread() {
    std::cout<<"Server::recvThread::started.\n"));
    try {
        do {
            {
                std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                if (m_isShutdown || m_needsReset) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // This loop reads the message size first before it reads the actual payload
            int requestLenBuffer = 0;  // Request size
            ssize_t bytesRead = recv(m_socketId, &requestLenBuffer, sizeof(int), 0);
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                int requestLenBufferInHostBytes = ntohl(requestLenBuffer);
                std::cout<<.d("request size.", requestLenBufferInHostBytes));
                ssize_t bytesRemaining = requestLenBufferInHostBytes;
                ssize_t totalBytesRead = 0;
                std::vector<unsigned char> byteBuffer(bytesRemaining + 1);  // +1 for the NUL-terminator
                bool joinThread = false;
                // Read the request
                while (bytesRemaining > 0) {
                    ssize_t bytesRead = recv(m_socketId, byteBuffer.data() + totalBytesRead, bytesRemaining, 0);
                    if (bytesRead > 0) {
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                        bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
                        continue;

                    } else if (!bytesRead) {
                        std::cout<<"Server:recvThread::connection closed.\n";
                        joinThread = true;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        std::cout<<"Server:recvThread"<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
                        joinThread = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (joinThread) {
                    break;
                }

                byteBuffer[requestLenBufferInHostBytes] = '\0';  // NUL-terminate the string
                std::cout<<"Recieved Request: "<<byteBuffer.data()<<"\n";

                Message message = createMessageFromBuffer(byteBuffer);
                
            } else if (!bytesRead) {
                std::cout<<"Server:recvThread::connection closed.\n";
                break;
            } else {
                std::cout<<"Server:recvThread"<<strerror(errno)<<"\n";
                break;
            }
        } while (true);
        {
            std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
            if (!m_isShutdown && !m_needsReset) {
                m_needsReset = true;
                std::cout << "RecvThread1\n";
                try {
                  m_resetThread = std::thread(&Server::resetThread, this);

                } catch (const std::exception &e) {
                    std::cout<<"exception"<<e.what()<<"\n";
                }
                std::cout << "RecvThread2\n";

            }
        }
    }catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout<<"exception"<<e.what()<<"\n";
    }
    std::cout<<"Server::recvThread::completed\n";
}

Message Server::createMessageFromBuffer(std::vector<unsigned char>& byteBuffer) {
    /// process buffer to create message
    return message;
}

From console output:
...
Server:sendThread:Sending Payload=...
Server:sendThread:Sending Payload=...
Server:recvThread::connection closed.
RecvThread1
RecvThread2
Server:resetThread::started.
Server:cleanUp
Server:recvThread::completed
Server:sendThread::completed.
Server:joinThreads
Server:listen
Server:listen::SocketServer is listening.:port=49152
Server:acceptThread::started.
Server:resetThread::completed.
Server:sendThread::started.
Server:recvThread::started.
Server:acceptThread::completed.
Server:recvThread:request size.=160
Server:recvThread:Recieved Request: = ...
Server:createMessageFromBuffer

Server:sendThread:Sending Payload=...
Server:sendThread:Sending Payload=...
Server:recvThread::connection closed.
RecvThread1
libc++abi: terminatingServer:resetThread::started.

Server:cleanUp

As can be seen from the console, if the socket is closed the first time, resetThread cleans everything up and the client can reconnect and send messages again, but the second time the client disconnects I see the exception.
I also enclosed restarting the resetThread in a try..catch block to catch the exception, but it seems like no exception is being caught there, so I need pointers as to what I might be missing here, or debug tips to the root cause of the issue, and to understand why the reset codepath is working only the first time.

Note: Need help debugging an exception in a multithread server class is a statement, not a question. I recommend working the title over.

"I cannot debug the application" - why not? StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service.

The trace suggests that a thread is already running when it is assigned over. This thread needs to be exited or detached (but detach generally leads to more problems later) before it can be disposed of.

@user4581301 i did consider resetThread not completed since the i only see RecvThread1 but not RecvThread2 in the logs but then i do see Server:resetThread::completed. in the logs before that seems to suggest that resetThread did complete unless i am missing something here. m_resetThraed is also a class variable so it should be destroyed until the class is destroyed. I will work on the title.

@RemyLebeau this application is build using a custom build system and putting console prints is how we debug it. I was able to launch the app manually , attached a debugger by clicking the running process and than let the client disconnect twice  to get the callstack.

Tactical note: 4 threads per socket is a lot of threads to have to wrangle. You can most likely dramatically reduce the amount of threads in use with an IO multiplexer like overlapped IO or select

If you can attach to the process and then click, you could attach to the process, place a breakpoint or two, and then click and step though the code when the breakpoint is hit. Often it is tricky to catch a race condition because breakpoints and stepping seriously  with the flow of the program, but maybe you can get lucky.

@bourne "I was able to launch the app manually, attached a debugger by clicking the running process and than let the client disconnect twice to get the callstack" - once the debugger is attached to the process, you should be able to debug the code normally. Especially since you are able to get the call stack, then you should be able to step through the code, etc as well.

@bourne All you've really done here is state a problem and dump a bunch of code expecting someone else to debug it for you. That is not how this site works.

Villain is probably m_resetThread = std::thread(&Server::resetThread, this); I see no signs of m_resetThread having been shut down and it looks like you're trapped into a kind of multi-threaded recusion. Receive thread starts reset thread, reset thread listens and starts accept thread which if I go digging deep enough I'll probably find accept thread starts the receive thread. You're shooting yourself in the foot with all of these threads.

@user4581301 i did add m_resetThread.join(); before m_resetThread = std::thread(&Server::resetThread, this); but still seeing the same issue but i understand your point that maybe having all these treads are unnecessary.

@RemyLebeau i am not able to put a breakpoint but let me look into that. That was not my intention , my idea was to help understand why this works the first time and not other time because to me it looks like this has to do something with m_resetThread and i am able to join it before and than start it again, but wanted to see if that is the right understanding or do i look elsewhere to root cause the issue.

@user4581301 This server class was designed such that the main thread invokes listen method that used to start recv and send thread once an incoming connection was established in acceptThread and than accept thread would join whereas send and recv thread would run. The issue i was trying to solve was that if there is a disconnection from client than cleanup and restart listening and therefore i was trying with this resetThread and that it should be started only once either by sendThread or recvThread during socket close. Any pointers on how to restructure the code better than what i am doing.

Take a look at what Beej is doing here. Instead of handling the client data in the main thread, you may want to kick it off to its own thread, or (better) a thread pool. This doesn't scale to large numbers of simultaneous clients, but if you only have a few clients (tens, maybe hundreds) it doesn't get much easier. Note this is the raw POSIX way to do it and it works OK on Windows. There are  improvements on this theme in Linux, and in Windows you use the same idea to get high performance, but it's written totally differently.

@user4581301 ok i will have a look so if i understand correctly, your suggestion is to use non blocking sockets instead and use ::select to find whether write/read/error has happened and do ::select loop on its own thread, and in the case of error you would be able to figure out whether you want to continue with the loop or exit depending on whether socket got disconnect from client or due to shutdown being invoked on Server class itself, is that the right understanding.

just one clarification you mentioned aove that there are There are improvements on this theme in Linux to get high performance, but it is written totally differently . If you have some resources/examples  on those esp related to linux, please do share, so that i can have a look .

@bourne WHY are you shutting down and resetting the listening socket just because a client disconnected? You should NOT be doing that in the first place. Just open the listen socket once and leave it open until you are done working with clients completely. When accept() reports a new client is connected, start your read/write threads for that client, and then go back to accept() when you are ready for a new client. No need to keep closing and reopening the listen socket.

How much portability do you need? Are you strictly targeting one OS? If you have to, or want to in the future, support multiple OSes, I strongly recommend looking into Boost ASIO. It's a fair amount of work to set up Boost (hint: Use a package manager to manage your tools and libraries where possible) and depending on how much existing network programming knowledge you have it may be a struggle to adapt to the ASIO way of thinking. But portability and good performance comes right out of the box.

@RemyLebeau thats is so true and now that i think about it , is totally unnecessary , i can have the accept thread keep listening and start revc/send thread per incoming thread and should only quit when shutdown is invoked. That way the only thread that i want to join during socket close by client are the send and recieve thread.Sorry still getting familiarized with socket programming.

A note about select: That third set of socket descriptors are not for errors. They are  for exceptional events. The errors are still handled through inspecting the return codes from the standard network calls. You will probably not need to do anything "exceptional", and can usually ignore, set to NULL the exceptfds argument.

General flow is set up the listener socket and add  it to the readfds set. When select tells you there's data, you check which fds are set. If the listen socket is set, you accept and add the accepted socket to the readfds set.  If a data socket is set, you recv the data out of it. The whole job can be one thread, but often the data received from the client will kick off other processing that you may want to perform in another thread so that the main thread can keep on processing network requests.

@user4581301 "That third set of socket descriptors are not for errors" - that depends on the platform. For instance, on Windows, it CAN be used for reporting errors (namely, when a non-blocking connect() failed, which doesn't apply in this case).

Did not know Windows did that. Thanks, @Remy .

Side note: the fd sets are updated by select, that's how select tells you what fds you need to inspect, so you can't just add a fd once as one of my above comments implies. But nothing prevents you from adding to an fd set once and passing a copy of that set to select to process. Depending on how much stuff is going on, it may be more effective to completely regenerate the set every time, though. But if you cache the fd sets, it's on you to remove closed connections.

Just be aware that select() has a limitation on the number of descriptors it can handle, and that size can be quite low on some platforms. So, if you have a lot of sockets to monitor, you should consider using (e)poll() instead (and, you don't need to make copies with it). But the same general concept applies to both select() and (e)poll() in regards to registering which sockets to monitor and detecting which sockets to act on.
